# Powershell - extract first and third element from string variable

Tags: string, powershell, extract

I have a variable called $Disk which is populated via a foreach loop that processes the output of a command that returns many lines of output.

For each iteration of the loop the $Disk variable contains data similar to:

```
Harddisk4  Disk1  SQLDG1  MBR   0     0   Offline     DISKS@SERVER1    P4C0T0L3 - -    F6799A78-9C10-443C-B4E6-22E3B30563C0 60003FFF409638B0B4E622E3B30563C0
```

I need to extract the first and third words from this string; all “words” in the string can be of variable length.

I would like to end up with:

`$Harddisk` equal to: `Harddisk4`

`$DG` equal to: `SQLDG1`

So far I have not found a way to do this. What options does powershell have to accomplish this?

Comment: What program produces this output? I'm wondering if there might be a managed equivalent...

Comment: (Commenting on an old post, I know)

I would like to point out that, while there may have been a good reason the OP was needing to parse pure text output, this isn't the "Powershell way", and might now be served by a relevant cmdlet/module.

I can't quite tell what was generating the output, but (all things being equal), grabbing the object from invoking get-disk on the target hosts and filtering/selecting from that would be the 'expected' approach.

Answer (score 3):

Marcus's answer is very elegnate using named matches

To show another approach, as there is always another

```
ForEach($line in $Document){
    $splitUp = $line -split "\s+"
    $Harddisk = $splitUp[0]
    $DG = $splitUp[2]
    ... other code stuff
}
```

**or** from pipeline

```
Get-Content c:\somefile.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $splitUp = $_ -split "\s+"
    $Harddisk = $splitUp[0]
    $DG = $splitUp[2]
    ... other code stuff
}
```

`\s+` will split the line on any group of whitespace leaving you every single word. That might be any issue with some text but as long as the details you are looking for do not contain spaces it will suit. `0` and `2` would represent the 1st and 3rd entries in a base 0 array.

Would give the following output for `$Harddisk` and `$DG`.

```
Harddisk4
SQLDG1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you wanted the values outputed into 2 variables it requires a bit of fiddling. The best I could do is:

```
$arr = $Disk -split "  "; $Harddisk=$arr[0]; $DG = $arr[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use a regular expression to process each line, depending on what your exact input format is, it could look something like this:

```
foreach($Disk in (Get-ManyLinesOfOutput)) {
   if ($Disk -match "^(?<harddisk>\S+) \w+ (?<dg>\S+)") {
       $Harddisk = $matches["harddisk"];
       $DG = $matches["dg"];
       # do something
   }
}
```

For the .NET regular expression syntax used by PowerShell see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt,

Here's what I ended up using for the Security Event-log events for account lock outs.

```
#Event Log Information
$EventInfo = Get-EventLog "Security" | Where {$30MinutesAgo -le $_.TimeWritten -and $_.eventid -eq 4740} | Format-List | Out-String 
ForEach ($line in $EventInfo){
    #Split line with ReplacementStrings : {accountname, computer, S-1..., S-1-5...} line
    $splitUp = $line -split "{"
    $EvReplacementStrings = $splitUp[1] -split ", "
    $EvUserName = $EvReplacementStrings[0]
    $EvComputer = $EvReplacementStrings[1]
}
```